# Netlify deployment of Gatsby/Wordpress site failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, gatsby, netlify

I am working on a site built with Gatsby/React, which sends an API call to a WordPress server at build-time in order to retrieve a list of blog posts. While the 'gatsby-build' and 'gatsby develop' commands both works locally without errors, when I go to deploy the site on Netlify, the deploy always fails with this error:

```
error "gatsby-source-wordpress" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Apparently, it's failing to retrieve the API data from WordPress each time. I am using environment variables in Netlify and I've triple checked that they're accurate; my WordPress site is also deployed on digitalOcean, and it's that droplet's IPv4 address that my site should be pinging. I've tried setting the restApiRoutePrefix setting to true/false/empty-string with failures each time. The protocol is set to HTTPS.

**gatsby.config.js**

```
  path: `.env`,
})



module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Alex Dollard`,
    description: `This is Alex fucking around. Hello!`,
    author: `@acdollard`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
        {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
      options: {
        /*
         * The base URL of the WordPress site without the trailingslash and the protocol. This is required.
         * Example : 'demo.wp-api.org' or 'www.example-site.com'
         */
        minimizeDeprecationNotice: true,
        baseUrl: process.env.API_URL,
        // The protocol. This can be http or https.
        protocol: process.env.API_PROTOCOL,

        restApiRoutePrefix: "wp-json",

        hostingWPCOM: false,

        useACF: true,

        acfOptionPageIds: [],
        auth: {
          // If auth.user and auth.pass are filled, then the source plugin will be allowed
          // to access endpoints that are protected with .htaccess.
          htaccess_user: "your-htaccess-username",
          htaccess_pass: "your-htaccess-password",
          htaccess_sendImmediately: false,

          // see https://en.support.wordpress.com/security/two-step-authentication/#application-specific-passwords
          wpcom_app_clientSecret: process.env.WORDPRESS_CLIENT_SECRET,
          wpcom_app_clientId: "54793",
          wpcom_user: "alexdollard141@gmail.com",
          wpcom_pass: process.env.WORDPRESS_PASSWORD,

          jwt_user: process.env.JWT_USER,
          jwt_pass: process.env.JWT_PASSWORD,
          jwt_base_path: "/jwt-auth/v1/token", // Default - can skip if you are using https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/
        },
        // Set cookies that should be send with requests to WordPress as key value pairs
        cookies: {},
        // Set verboseOutput to true to display a verbose output on `npm run develop` or `npm run build`
        // It can help you debug specific API Endpoints problems.
        verboseOutput: false,
        // Set how many pages are retrieved per API request.
        perPage: 100,
        // Search and Replace Urls across WordPress content.
        searchAndReplaceContentUrls: {
          sourceUrl: "https://source-url.com",
          replacementUrl: "https://replacement-url.com",
        },
        // Set how many simultaneous requests are sent at once.
        concurrentRequests: 10,

        includedRoutes: [
          "**/categories",
          "**/posts",
          "**/pages",
          "**/media",
          "**/tags",
          "**/taxonomies",
          "**/users",
        ],
        // Blacklisted routes using glob patterns
        excludedRoutes: ["**/posts/1456"],
        // Set this to keep media sizes.
        // This option is particularly useful in case you need access to
        // URLs for thumbnails, or any other media detail.
        // Defaults to false
        keepMediaSizes: false,
        // use a custom normalizer which is applied after the built-in ones.
        normalizer: function ({ entities }) {
          return entities
        },
   
        normalizers: normalizers => [
          ...normalizers,
          {
            name: "nameOfTheFunction",
            normalizer: function ({ entities }) {
              // manipulate entities here
              return entities
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Alex Dollard <alexdollard141@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.24.91",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.12.117",
    "gatsby-core-utils": "^1.3.24",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.19",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.30",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.28",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.36",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.4.0",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^3.3.36",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental": "^1.7.9",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.15",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.27.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.1.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass --watch src/sass -o src/css",
    "devserver": "live-server --port=8000 --open=public --entry-file=index.html",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass src/sass/main.scss src/css/main.css",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/acdollard/first_gatsby_site"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Does this sound like a netlify problem, a gatsby problem, or a wordpress problem? Do I need to include any other code/file snippets to help clarify the problem? Any help much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue relies on your [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/). When dealing with them  in Netlify, they must be prefixed with `GATSBY_` in order to make them available to Netlify. Change them respectively to:

```
baseUrl: process.env.GATSBY_API_URL,
protocol: process.env.GATSBY_API_PROTOCOL,
wpcom_app_clientSecret: process.env.GATSBY_WORDPRESS_CLIENT_SECRET,
wpcom_pass: process.env.GATSBY_WORDPRESS_PASSWORD,
jwt_user: process.env.GATSBY_JWT_USER,
jwt_pass: process.env.GATSBY_JWT_PASSWORD,
```

Change your local environment files too and add them in the Netlify dashboard under https://app.netlify.com/sites/YOUR_SITE/settings/deploys#environment:

[image]

And so on for the rest...

What's happening is that Netlify can't read your environment variables, so can't fetch your data (becoming `null` or `undefined`) and throws an exception because it is not able to keep the build process.

References:

- https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-access-environment-variables/1240
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/

Comment: Thank you Ferran! I changed all my . env variables in Netlify and my local, and now i'm getting this slightly different error: 

```error "gatsby-source-wordpress" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:
11:36:28 AM: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```
it also throws these messages right before error-ing out: 
```11:36:28 AM: Path: /wp-json
11:36:28 AM: The server response was "404 Not Found"
```
that /wp-json part makes me think it has something to do with the restApiRoutePrefix but I really don't know. Does digitalOcean change the way WP-rest-api works?

Comment: Did you add ALL your environment variables to Netlify's dashboard? Does it build locally now?

Comment: truth  be told I'm only defining two environment variables locally, GATSBY_API_URL and GATSBY_API_PROTOCOL. Everything else came out of the box, but went ahead and changed all the env.variables in the local file anyway. Should I not have done that? *and yes, it builds locally

Comment: yes I added all the variables to Netlify's dashboard even the empty ones

Comment: All your variables should be defined as well as locally and in the server (Netlify). How are you getting `process.env.GATSBY_JWT_USER` if not? Both sides prefixed with `GATSBY_` (despite being only a Netlify requirement, it keeps the coherence of the code).

Comment: ok I see. (I actually took out that whole auth object and the gatsby build command still worked fine.)
I'm starting to think that it's an issue with the GATSBY_API_URL variable itself though because when I change the URL from localhost:10039 to wp.alexdollard.xyz (which is where my Wordpress site lives) then the build fails locally. I have the variable defined as wp.alexdollard.xyz in Netlify is that the wrong format or something?